# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two n-digit numbers - python

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

I am solving this leetcode problem and the description goes like this,

```
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two n-digit numbers.

Since the result could be very large, you should return the largest palindrome mod 1337.

Example:

Input: 2

Output: 987

Explanation: 99 x 91 = 9009, 9009 % 1337 = 987
```

My current solution works only if the value of n is 4 or less. I tried to modify it, but looks like I need some help in figuring it out. How do I solve it in less time ? This is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def largestPalindrome(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if (n == 1):  #it returns '9' if the input is a single digit number
            return 9
        highest = 0
        high = '9'  
        low = '1'
        for k in range(2,n+1):
            high = high + '9' #increase the number of digits until 'n' is reached
            low = low + '0'  
            for i in range(int(low), int(high)-1): 
                for j in range(int(low) + 1, int(high)):
                    num = str(i * j)
                    if (int(num) > highest and num == num[::-1]):  # if it is a palindrome and highest then 
                        highest = int(num)  # highest  is the new number
        return highest % 1337
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed this up quite a lot by getting rid of unnecessary cases. For starters:

- Because the order of the two integers doesn't matter, you only need to consider the cases where j >= i, so you can set the lower bound for your j-loop at j=i. (Or possibly higher; see below.)
- Because you are looking for the LARGEST palindrome, you can save yourself a lot of time by looping i and j from highest to lowest values instead of lowest to highest. For each i, you can stop the j-loop as soon as you find the first (highest) j that gives i*j = palindrome, because any lower value of j would give a smaller palindrome.
- You can use your highest-so-far palindrome to set smarter lower bounds on j. There is no point in checking any j-values smaller than highest/i because even if these do give you a palindrome, this would be smaller than the one you already have.

Another approach: instead of looping through i and j, loop on possible palindromes. Start at the largest possible palindrome with 2n digits, and test whether it is possible to express it as a product of two n-digit numbers; if you're careful with the bounds you set on possible factors, this shouldn't require checking many cases. If if can be expressed as a product, you're done; if not, try the next palindrome down, and repeat until you find something that works.